# how to fetch uber login page then redirect to statements page using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, uber-api

i'm trying to fetch https://partners.uber.com/statements/cdf3d725-da5d-3ea2-1985-b8b09a6249d9

but i didn't get the requested page

i tried many solutions have been published here but it didn't help

username and password are checked

```
function getData() {

var target = "https://partners.uber.com/statements/cdf3d725-da5d-3ea2-1985-b8b09a6249d9";

var username = "user@gmail.com";
var pass = "pass";

var headers = {

"Authorization" : "Bearer " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ':' + pass)};

var params = {
"method":"GET",
"headers":headers,
 "followRedirects": true

};

var pageTxt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(target,params).getContentText();
 Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(target,params).getResponseCode() );

Logger.log(pageTxt);
 var pageDoc = Xml.parse(pageTxt,true);


 var trs = pageDoc.getElement()
         .getElement("body")
           .getElements("div")[0]      
             .getElements("div")[3]    
                 .getElement("table")
                 .getElements("tbody")[1].getElements("tr");

     var col = pageDoc.getElement()
         .getElement("body")
           .getElements("div");    

   }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be scraping data from the partners site as it is against the terms of service.

Comment: your are right but it's my data .. i just want to import it to analyze it

Answer (score 0):

try this code block,

```
function myFunction() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://partners.uber.com/statements/cdf3d725-da5d-3ea2-1985-b8b09a6249d9",{muteHttpExceptions:true});

  Logger.log(response);

}
```

Comment: any help here please?

Comment: Hey .. your code is working I just tested it. how you getting 403?